# Makefile gives strange error while compiling markdown file into .docx file

Tags: r, docx, pandoc, r-markdown

I am having problems with makefile for creating docx file from rmd using R. 
Here is my make file, which patially works fine, except last part:

```
all: ibn_paper.pdf; cabg_n_cor_draft.docx
ibn_paper.md:
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('ibn_paper.Rmd')"
ibn_paper.pdf: ibn_paper.md
pandoc -H format.sty -V fontsize=12pt --bibliography ibn_refs.bib ibn_paper.md -o ibn_paper.pdf
cabg_n_cor_draft.docx: ibn_paper.md
    pandoc -s -S -V fontsize=12pt --bibliography ibn_refs.bib ibn_paper.md -o
cabg_n_cor_draft.docx

clean:
     @-rm -r *.md
```

And all this code works and creates at the end this error:

```
make: cabg_n_cor_draft.docx: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1

Exited with status 2.
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Many thanks beforehand.

Comment: 1) remove the `;` in the list of dependencies for `all` rule; 2) does it actually creates `cabg_n_cor_draft.docx`?

Comment: Yes, the pandoc line works fine in command line, if you mean that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove semicolon in the first line. You probably wanted to let `all` depend on the two files. But semicolon separates recipe from list of prerequisites.
Look at [makefile rule syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax)